# Changing tiles in Phaser.JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, phaser-framework

I have a tilemap with dirt tiles and grass tiles, in phaser 3, and I would like a function which:

1. if the tile above a dirt tile is removed, the dirt tile becomes a grass tile
2. if a dirt tile is placed with no tiles 1 block above it, it becomes a grass tile
3. if a grass tile has any block on top of it, it becomes a dirt tile

The code I have works for part 2, though its buggy, only becoming a grass tile sometimes, and not other times it should

code

```js
this.worldLayer.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        let wlTile = this.worldLayer.getTileAt(tile.x, tile.y);
        //dirt to grass
        if (
          wlTile != null &&
          wlTile.index == 2 &&
          this.worldLayer.getTileAt(tile.x, tile.y - 1) == null
        ) {
          this.worldLayer.removeTileAt(wlTile.x, wlTile.y);
          this.worldLayer.putTileAt(1, wlTile.x, wlTile.y);
        }
}
```

So how can I make it work for all these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be pretty straight forward, just add the a second condition to check for the grass part.

*(Here is your code adapted)*

```
this.worldLayer.forEachTile(function (tile) {
    let wlTile = this.worldLayer.getTileAt(tile.x, tile.y);

    if ( !wlTile ) {
        return;
    }

    if( wlTile.index == DIRT_INDEX && this.worldLayer.getTileAt(tile.x, tile.y - 1) == null ) {
        this.worldLayer.putTileAt(GRASS_INDEX, tile.x, tile.y);
    } else if( wlTile.index == GRASS_INDEX && this.worldLayer.getTileAt(tile.x, tile.y - 1) ) {
        this.worldLayer.putTileAt(DIRT_INDEX, tile.x, tile.y); 
    }
});
```

Nevertheless it migth be better to do this *on click* and not iterate through the whole tilemap. You can use the same conditions.

> Depending on how you are removing you tiles *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html#removeTileAt__anchor))*, you would have to adapt the `if` - conditions to fit the possibility, that the above tile is a tile but has the index `-1`.

**Here an example for the dirt-part:**

```
let tileAbove = this.worldLayer.getTileAt(tile.x, tile.y - 1);
if( wlTile.index == DIRT_INDEX && ( tileAbove == null || tileAbove.index == -1)
 ){ ... }
```